# AWS SSH into EC2 server timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ssh

About 6 months ago I created an AWS EC2 instance to mess around with on the free tier. After months of having no issues remoting into my AWS EC2 server, I've recently been unable to access it via SSH. I am using the following command:

```
ssh -i my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-**-**-***-***.us-****-*.compute.amazonaws.com
```

...and after a minute or two, am getting this response

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-**-**-***-***.us-****-*.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

What's strange is that

1) I can read and write to my RDS database just fine

2) I can ping into the server

3) My port 22 is open

4) The instance is running and healthy

5) In the Inbound section of the security group of the EC2 server it allows for all traffic and SSH from any location via port 22.

6) I'm using the same key-pair as always

I went through this documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html) and can confirm that the VPC, subnet, network ACL and route tables all line up (I haven't changed anything with those since the SSH stopped working). Any insight would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Did you consider speaking with AWS support?

Answer (score -1):

- Sometimes the instance fails, you can check the screen of it via AWS
  console.
- Run another instance in the same security group and try to
  connect to it and then from there to your original one - to verify if
  ssh is still open (even if you do not have the ssh key, the error
  will not be 'timeout')
- You can create a snapshot of your instance and
  attach it as another volume in a new one and you can investigate
  logs, maybe something went wrong.
- You can restart the instance, if
  for example i ran out of memory it will most likely work after the
  reboot (hopefully for a long enough time for you to investigate).
- You can contact AWS support.